# Can I use a copyrighted work made by a company if that company is out of business?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

So I have considered sharing music clips made by a company and am worried about getting sued. The company in question has gone out of business a few years ago. I also tried to look up the work in question and the name of the company on the website of the Canadian Intellectual Property Office (The company in question used to be based in Canada) and on the website of the US Copyright Office, and these attempts have yielded no results. Does anyone still have copyright over the works? If not, can I use it?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, someone still owns the copyright

### No, you can’t use it without their permission

If the business was run by a now defunct company the assets of that company (including IP) would have passed to the company’s assignees - the creditors if the company was liquidated or the shareholders if it was wound up.

If the business was run by individuals then they still own the copyright.